# Get all model records associated with a different model's set of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to get a collection of "posts" that were made in the past day, and get all of their author's emails.

An `author has_many posts`.

Step 1: Get all posts created today (works)

```
Posts.where('created_at > :today', today: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Step 2: Get all authors for these posts (what is the syntax for this?)

```
Posts.where('created_at > :today', today: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).authors??? # Returns undefined method for ActiveRecord_Relation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eager load author

```
Posts.includes(:author).where('created_at > :today', today: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).collect(&:author)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get array of emails that way:

```
Posts.where('created_at > :today', today: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).joins(:author).pluck("authors.email")
```

If you need `ActiveRecord::Relation` than you must start your query with class which you want to get

```
Author.joins(:posts).where("posts.created_at > :today", today: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```